# Install node.js in windows using script

Tags: node.js, windows

Is it possible to install node.js in windows using script or cmd command?

I want to create a installer that will also install nodejs.

Comment: As far as i know the answer is no.

Comment: Node.js has a Windows installer...

Comment: thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can just have the installer download the NodeJS MSI from the website and use `msiexec` to install it.